# Write elements to a Linkedlist

Tags: python

I have such a ListNode

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None
```

and a linkedlist

```
 Input: l1: 1->2->4, ll2:1->3->4
```

How could add the numbers to list?

I tried

```
head = ListNode(0)
node1 = ListNode(head)
node1.next = node2 #but node2 has not been declared
node2 = ListNode(2)
node2.next = node3 #node3 has not been declared
node3 = ListNode(4)
node3.next = null
```

I think I need some Listnode thing like `d = defaultdict(int).` then I can use d[] before assignment.

Comment: Why not just create `node2` before linking to it from `node1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will run:

```
head = ListNode(0)
node1 = ListNode(head) # <-- is this really what you want
node2 = ListNode(2)
node3 = ListNode(4)

node1.next = node2
node2.next = node3
node3.next = null # <-- or maybe it won't
```

but isn't this what you want:

```
head = ListNode(0)
node1 = ListNode(1)
node2 = ListNode(2)
node3 = ListNode(4)

head.next = node1
node1.next = node2
node2.next = node3
# node3.next = None  # <-- this is redundant
```

If you defined your class like this:

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, x, next=None):
        self.val = x
        self.next = next
```

You could do:

```
head = ListNode(0, ListNode(1, ListNode(2, ListNode(4))))
```

but maybe you want all the intermediate references to the nodes

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this by adding a factory method to my node class-

## Definition for singly-linked list.

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None
    def link(value):
        node = ListNode(value)
        self.next = node
        return node
```

Then your initialization code becomes...

```
head = ListNode(0)
head.link(2).link(4).link(6)
```